# toString only works with parenthesis or non-literal numbers

Tags: javascript, string, tostring, parentheses

For some reason, when I try to call `toString` on a literal number, it fails:

```
> 5.toString()
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

So I tried putting it in a variable, and it worked:

```
> var five = 5
undefined
> five.toString()
"5"
```

I thought that was a bit strange, and after some more experimenting, I found out that wrapping a literal in parenthesis somehow makes it work:

```
> (5).toString()
"5"
```

That seemed *very* strange! Why would wrapping the literal in parenthesis change anything? Why does `5.toString()` not work?

Comment: @Musa Oh thanks, I didn't find that because I thought it had to do with `toString` and not calling methods on numbers :P

Comment: @ShahroozJefri Why did you edit that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dot `.` after the number represents a decimal point.

It would work if you do;

```
5..toString();
```

To clarify when a decimal point is followed by a number in javascript it expects the next character to be that of a number, so if `toString()` is there instead it is considered an illegal token as `t` is not a valid number.

This is another valid way of doing the same thing but is easier to read and follow;

```
5.0.toString();
```

Comment: That's strange. Thanks! I can accept the answer in 7 minutes

Comment: I added an explaination for you,

Answer (score 2):

Why would wrapping the literal in parenthesis change anything?

This causes the literal to become an expression. As a result, you can call the method `.toString()` on the expression. As linked by @Musa, the `.` after a number is interpreted as a decimal point causing an exception to be thrown when 5.t is encountered as t is not a valid number.